# ESP-IDF || CORE dump

Tags: embedded, esp32, freertos, rtos, esp-idf

I was writing a simple program for the led blink, the program was working fine with `GPIO_NUM_2` but when the led pin num is changed to `GPIO_NUM_2` the program started behave oddly, and I don't know why that is happening. Please explain what mistake I am making.

```c
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"


# define led1 GPIO_NUM_7


void task1(void* pvParametes){
    gpio_reset_pin(led1);
    gpio_set_direction(led1, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    while (true)    
    {
        gpio_set_level(led1, 1);
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        gpio_set_level(led1, 0);
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    xTaskCreate(task1, "LedBlink", 4096, NULL, 1, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Define "behave oddly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPIOs 6 to 11 are usually connected to the SPI flash memory. If you try to use them for something else, the MCU can no longer read the program it is executing and will fail.